# Can summation and product notations be used in a single line of Python code?

Tags: python, sum, product, notation

I am currently working with a few mathematical problems. Some involve double summations while others involve double products. Some include a combination summation with a product.

Python permits double summation in a single line of code. Take the example:

[image: \sum_{x=1}^{2}\left ( \sum_{y=1}^{3} \left ( x+y \right )\right )= 21]

This can be simply solved with a single code line:

```
>>> sum((x + y) for y in range(1,4) for x in range(1,3))
21
```

Similarly, double products can be calculated with a single line of code. Example:

[image: \prod_{x=1}^{2}\left ( \prod_{y=1}^{3} \left ( x+y \right )\right )= 1440]

And the coded solution using Python 3.8:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.prod((x + y) for y in range(1,4) for x in range(1,3))
1440
```

How can I complete a similar problem that includes a single summation and a single product? Is it possible using a single line of code? For example:

[image: \sum_{x=1}^{2}\left ( \prod_{y=1}^{3} \left ( x+y \right )\right )= 84]

I thought this may be as simple as:

```
>>> sum((math.prod(x + y)) for y in range(1,4) for x in range(1,3))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

but `print(dir(sum))` and `print(dir(math.prod))` show the magic method `__iter__` is absent from both sum and math.prod, hence the TypeError.

I know I can use a for loop like this:

```
>>> ans = 0
>>> for x in range(1,3):
...         ans += math.prod((x + y) for y in range(1,4))
>>> ans
84
```

but this gets a little untidy when I have more summations and products in the same equation (up to four, occasionally more).

Is there a simple single code line approach for combining summations and products I’m missing? Or is the for loop method the only way? Any thoughts?

Comment: You have misinterpreted the error message you get from your first attempt. The problem is that `x + y` is a scalar value, so you cannot compute a `prod`uct of the sequence as there is no sequence. Similarly, if you fixed the `math.prod` call, it would return a single (scalar) integer value, which cannot be `sum`med.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses in the mathematical notation are your guide. What we need to do is to consider each summation/product step separately.

When we perform the sum of products, each product is of the form

```
math.prod(x + y for y in range(1, 4))
```

(Note that parentheses around `x + y` are not necessary.)

Notice that `x` is undefined here - so far, it is a free variable (in math-speak).

So, we bind it when we perform the summation:

```
sum(math.prod(x + y for y in range(1, 4)) for x in range(1, 3))
```

which evaluates to the desired `84`.

It helps here to understand the theory underlying the syntactic constructs. When we write `sum(f(x) for x in xs)`, we are passing a *generator expression* to the built-in `sum` function. This functions similarly to a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) (which in turn is built upon the mathematical concept of set-builder notation), except that the elements will be determined on-demand as `sum` iterates over them, rather than being eagerly evaluated and stored in memory all at once. Normally, a generator expression would be written using an enclosing pair of parentheses, thus `(f(x) for x in xs)`; Python has a special syntax rule such that, when you call a function with a *single* argument which is a generator expression, you can omit this pair of parentheses (since they would be redundant with the ones used for the function call).

For more detail on list comprehensions, please see [Trey Hunner's excellent guide](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/). The basic technique applies equally to all sorts of comprehensions in Python as well as to generator expressions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your well-considered and structured answer - I appreciate the effort you put into your reply. The link to Trey Hunner's guide is also most appreciated. I am currently halfway through and I have already learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(math.prod(x + y for y in range(1, 4)) for x in range(1, 3))
```